# SSRS chart axis showing a label for 0 even though my numbers go from -1 to 1

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I work at a theater and have an SSRS chart that shows sales for weeks before and after the beginning of the run of a show. The X axis labels are week numbers. For the weeks before the show starts, they are negative numbers, for example: -3 is 3 weeks before the first show. Then the first week of the show is Week 1, and so on.

There is no such thing as Week 0. The data coming from the stored procedure reflects this and doesn't send data for a Week 0, but SSRS is insisting on putting 0 along the X axis anyway.

How can I make it only show the weeks that exist? I thought there would be a way to tell SSRS to consider the numbers as though they were text labels but I can't find such a control.

Comment: Can you show the query you are using to pull data from sql server?

Comment: Thanks for responding, M. Ali. The query is not the problem as I had verified the stored procedure returns the week numbers correctly. 

Someone I know helped me fix it -- she changed the x axis type from scalar to category with interval 1. :)

Comment: Well can you provide some sort of mock data to reproduce the issue only then someone can give you a solution.

Comment: Aha, I see why you were asking now. I will remember that in the future if I post another question, but my friend got me the solution as posted below so I don't need anymore help. Thank you so much for attempting to assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the x axis type from scalar to category with interval 1.